# Projective representations of loop groups

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory

If $G$ is a Lie group and we take its loop group $LG$ why do we deal with projective representations of $LG$ and central extensions thereof? Where does the extra complexity come in to require us to consider this extra, very complicated, step?

Comment: When are you ever _required_ to do anything in mathematics?

Comment: I asked this because I am reading about these on behest of my advisor with little motivation. I told him I was keen on mathematical physics and he told me to read Loop groups by Segal and Pressley.

Comment: It just seems like strange wording to me. Nobody is _required_ to centrally extend a loop group. People _want to_ centrally extend loop groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projective representations are needed in quantum mechanics, and I think that is the main motivation behind studying projective representations. The point is that in QM, it is rays in a Hilbert space which have physical meaning. So the symmetry group is required to act on and transform these rays rather than vectors.

Comment: So the representations we study happen to be projective because of some physical meaning? Is there no mathematical reason?

Comment: I am not sure. If there is any mathematical reason I too would like to know :)

Comment: But from Lie algebra point of view study of projective representations will also give you ordinary ones. Right ?

Comment: @Sven: I disagree with the premise that a physical justification for studying projective representations is not a mathematical justification for studying projective representations. Much of mathematics owes its existence to physical considerations and this seems disrespectful of the role of physics in mathematics to me.

Comment: I meant no offense, if it were a physical constraint I would be perfectly happy with that explanation. I asked because in my limited experience the physical constraint is not independent of a mathematical one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we are usually concerned about these exotic objects at the algebraic level. They pop up when we consider spinor representations of the orthogonal group. Lets write $\gamma_{\alpha}$ for the generators of the Clifford algebra which are represented by $\Gamma_{\alpha}$. They satisfy
$$\Gamma_{\alpha}\Gamma_{\beta}+\Gamma_{\beta}\Gamma_{\alpha}=2\eta_{\alpha\beta}$$
where $\eta_{\alpha\beta}$ is nondegenerate. (If it's degenerate, we have a Grassmann algebra and not a Clifford algebra, but it's not terrible.)

So we have commutators of the generators of the Clifford algebra. We will leave it as an exercise for the reader to determine
$$[\Gamma_{\alpha},\Gamma_{\beta}]=\text{something quadratic}$$
and
$$[\Gamma_{\alpha},\Gamma_{\mu}\Gamma_{\nu}]=2\eta_{\alpha\mu}\Gamma_{\nu}-2\eta_{\alpha\nu}\Gamma_{\mu}.$$
Now we expect commutators of quadratic terms to look like
$$[\Gamma_{\alpha}\Gamma_{\beta},\Gamma_{\mu}\Gamma_{\nu}]\sim a\Gamma_{\sigma}\Gamma_{\tau}+b\cdot\textbf{1}$$
and wouldn't it be lovely if we could make this an equality and ditch the constant multiple of the identity operator $b\textbf{1}$? This would make the representation of quadratic guys a closed algebra!

We find if we write an arbitrary element of these generated algebra as $a\cdot\textbf{1}+b^{\mu\nu}\Gamma_{\mu}\Gamma_{\nu}$ (where we use Einstein summation convention) we have an algebra, provided one condition on the matrix $b^{\mu\nu}$ namely we need
$$ b^{\mu\nu}=-b^{\nu\mu}.$$
This says we have a "representation" of the orthogonal Lie algebra. Is it a representation? Yes and no. No, it's technically not a "vanilla representation"; but with all this extra structure, we have a *central extension* of the orthogonal lie algebra.

Wouldn't it be lovely, after all this work, if we could do the same thing to *other* Lie algebras? That's how we get started with losing ourselves in the jungle of loop groups, its central extensions, etc.